# Medicine vs. Medication

Tags: word-choice, terminology, medical

I'm wrote some documentation in which I needed to refer to the list of drugs that a person was taking at a given time. This list might also include a dosage as well (e.g. '*Aspirin 300mg daily*').

I used the term '*medication(s)*', but someone else suggested '*medicine(s)*' as an alternative. Personally, I think it sounds worse and may be less clear, as '*medicine*' can also refer to the general practice of medicine. But maybe that's just me.

Is there any reason why I should prefer one over the other?

<sup>Note: this is for labeling GUI elements and in related documentation.</sup>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Medications* is the proper term for substances used for medical treatment, esp. pharmaceuticals. People can self-medicate (and they do all the time). They don't self-medicine. Medications includes vitamins and other supplements people take for health reasons. The verb medicate (*[to treat medicinally](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/medication)*) is from 1620s. Health professionals usually refer to these as *meds*.

*Medicine*, though used by lay persons to indicate drugs, is actually the art or science of healing. There is holistic medicine, allopathic medicine, homeopathic medicine, etc.

On a medical chart, we often list *drugs/alcohol* separately, because it refers to illicit drugs.

We do not use the word prescriptions, because that would exclude over-the-counter medications the patient might be taking, e.g. aspirin, benadryl or other for allergies, decongestants, supplements, herbals, etc.

In addition to dosage, we usually have a space for *start* and *stop* dates for medications, as a past history of medications is important to know as well. It is important to know what the patient has taken before that has or hasn't worked for chronic or recurrent problems.

Comment: Thanks, this is kind of what I was thinking, but you've put it much more clearly. In the application we're designing the history of medications is not important (at least that's what I've been told; I'm not a medical professional).

Comment: Note that many dictionaries include medicine as a synonym of medication, and include "a drug or other preparation for the treatment or prevention of disease" as a definition of medicine - the "lay persons' definition" that you mention appears to have become a "legitimate" one.

Comment: My answer was given from a medical professional's viewpoint for the OP's context. Also, on a prescription bottle, the label refers to it's contents as medication (*do not drink of drive while on this mdication*.) The lay term is fine and understandable. I've never corrected someone asking if "there was any medicine they could take" for their illness.

Comment: Good one. So it should be medicinal values or medicational values? Well there not such a word as medicational...at least as per the dictionary.

Comment: @aspiring - it would be medicinal value. :-)

Comment: The two are synonyms in everyday speech, not formal papers or articles. It's really that simple.

Comment: Although it is certainly true that *medication* is now standardly  used for a **substance** administered to treat a disease, the reference to the verb *to medicate* in the first paragraph does not explain that. The existence of that verb supports using *medication* for the **action** of administering such substances, rather than for the substances themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at it as an outsider, it seems to me that it should be:

Medicine (noun) - 1) Referring to the field itself, the profession of healing.

Medication (noun) - 1) The act of using a method from the field of medicine to treat someone.

Medicate (verb) - 1) To treat someone using a method from the field of medicine.

As for the pills themselves, I would refer to them as pills, drugs, or as medical substances.

So when I hear someone say "Use this medication", I actually hear "Use this method of medication (the method of giving them this particular drug/substance/process)"

If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Neither term is preferable.

It is fashionable to say “medication” but both it and “medicine” mean drugs or other substances taken to treat or cure disease.

Any dictionary will verify this.

Answer (score 0):

I think *prescription* is the term to use in this case.

*Prescription:*

1. (Medicine)
   a. written instructions from a physician, dentist, etc, to a pharmacist stating the form, dosage strength, etc, of a drug to be issued to a specific patient.

Comment: This list might also include non-prescription drugs (e.g. Aspirin). Also, while a doctor can theoretically prescribe aspirin, I don't want to limit this to a list of drugs that has been prescribed (e.g. if the person is taking it without explicit instructions from a physician)

Comment: In that case I think you can refer to them as "a list of medications"

Comment: Prescription is the Intersection (cross-reference) of a Medication and a Patient.  Prescription would have data attached to it such as Start Date, End Date, Refills Allowed, Who Prescribed it and When, Custom Directions on how and when to take it, etc...  From a Database perspective I do not think of Aspirin as a Medication.  Instead "Aspirin" is a Generic Medication Type or Grouping you can give to Medications.  Medication either includes this Type/Grouping (or is linked to it elsewhere).  Medications typically include Brand Name, Dosage, how they are taken, an NDC Code, etc...